Firestore add method throws error "Error: 13 INTERNAL: An internal error occurred."
My Cloud Function is logging out this error while it is being called.
Error: 13 INTERNAL: An internal error occurred.
    at callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:192:76)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:360:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181)
    at /workspace/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:94:78
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)

This error is coming from this function:
const insert = await admin
   .firestore()
   .collection(myCollection)
   .add(insertFSObject)
   .catch((error) => {
      console.log(`Insert failed document ${insertFSObject.name} at ${insertFSObject.created}`)
      console.log(error);
   });

I have monitored my cloud functions and the error seems to be not appear again which is very weird because all the transactions and logs before or after the errors are successful calls. How can I fix this error when it is not frequently occurred.

It's not possible to fix all possible problems with complex cloud systems.  Errors can and will happen unpredictably, for a wide variety of reasons, and all you can do in those situations is capture the error and retry the code that failed.  This is especially true for errors like "internal error", where the problem is almost certainly not under control of your own code.

Yes, Doug. I think retrying the function when it fail is the only solution now. Sorry for the late response.

As Doug Stevenson already mentioned in his comment, such an error:

Error: 13 INTERNAL: An internal error occurred.

I can be thrown for many reasons. So in such cases, my recommendation is to retry the Cloud Function until it succeeds. For more info, please check @GünterZöchbauer answer from the following post:

Retry Cloud Functions for Firebase until it succeeds

This means that you should handle internal errors in your code very well so it will retry for any failure. In your code, you should use RuntimeOptions.failurePolicy which:

Failure policy of the function, with boolean true being equivalent to providing an empty retry object.


Hey there, Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Hi Alex, sorry for the late response. I have updated my cloud functions to have retry when there is a failure. So far there is no errors up to now. I need monitor more and thanks for the suggestion Alex

OK, keep me posted.
